# Excel 365 : How to prevent excel from locking file while editing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I just recently changed to using office 365 and am having issue with excel in particular.

I often have to use excel to modify certain xlsx files and upload it to our company website which then gives a preview of the changes made before finally updating our databases based on the changes, however I often have to do this for the same file multiple times in a row to make sure the changes are correct in the preview. But since the change, I have been unable to upload the file while having it open so I have to repeatedly open, edit, save, close the file, upload, open again whenever I need to upload. I did not have to close the file back when I was using Excel 2010

So my question is whether there is a way to stop excel from locking the file so I can upload the modified file without closing the file itself every time

This is the error message I get while selecting the file to upload which seems like implying the file is locked by excel

[image: Upload Error Message]

As a side note, I tried drag and dropping the file instead but Edge just shows the "Can't get this page" error without even reaching the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File locks are the function of the file system or file host, not really the application.

Multiple people working in the same file requires the file being hosted on a capable system such as SharePoint or OneDrive.

You cannot do this given a basic filesystem and computer or with a host that does not support this function.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely correct! Once I moved the file to a location that is not synced to onedrive, the issue dissapears. I hadn't changed computer so I just assumed it was Excel 365, while in fact was because I started to syncing my file to my OneDrive storage which comes with the O365 subscription! Thank you, now I just need to figure out how to disable that lock..

Comment: Sorry for using your comment section. Future people who have my exact issue can disable the feature in onedrive settings -> office -> uncheck "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open" as per this [article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_win10-mso_o365b/users-onedrive-files-are-locked-for-editing-and/21fd2eb7-6760-4862-a1ce-ed1a2b457901)